# Input youtube url from Mongodb

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb

I created a website with a training program, depending on which week you click on you will receive different exercises which will be taken from a mongo database. Within this data there is also a youtube url, I would like to also be able to take my url string and input it into some code so it appears with the exercises. I would like to receive your advice on the best plan of action, use an api and customize its use or take the url from mongo and input it into a html ? 
Thank you 
all the best

Comment: Are you going to use it only for the website or is there also another website/application that you want to get the same data? If that might be a future idea of you I strongly suggest you do this with an API.

Comment: @StuiterSlurf Thank you for the input, it seems like the best course of action.